# FreeMarker error: For "-" left-hand operand: Expected a number, but this has evaluated to a string

Tags: freemarker

I am trying to compute sum of values in map and print line of "-"s (the length of this line should be sum-1).
This is the code of my function:

```
<#function getSeparatorLine map>
    <#if !map?has_content>
        <#return "">
    </#if>
    <#local borderLength = 0>
    <#list map?keys as item>
        <#local borderLength = borderLength + item + 1>
    </#list>
    <#return ""?right_pad(borderLength - 1, "-")>
</#function>
```

I get a freemarker error saying:

```
ERROR freemarker.runtime - Error executing FreeMarker template
freemarker.core.NonNumericalException: For "-" left-hand operand: Expected a number, but this has evaluated to a string (wrapper: f.t.SimpleScalar):
==> borderLength  [in template "negative_events_report.template" at line 38, column 27]
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

`item` is a string, so `borderLength + item + 1` actually does string concatenation instead of arithmetical addition. Assuming `map` contains numerical values, you should write `map?values`, not `map?keys`.